# How much is it frowned upon by asking answer from a particular user directly in the comments?

Tags: discussion

There are often times when you know certain high-rep users have better understanding than others,and, there were couple of times I asked an user for the answer I was looking for, in the comments. To me if he did not knew, then such an answer do not exist.I know its a bad etiquette, and sometimes its a last minute desperate effort to get some attention for your question. However, 2 days waiting time for putting up on a bounty is long, and if you are low-rep user you seem to get into a lot of programming/technical issues a lot. So, how does SO views this if I ask a particular user,directly in the comments, who has a lot of expertise on a given area. I know its not wise, but I am looking for some thoughts here.

Comment: It is terrible bad form. Don't do it. If your question is well worded and tagged correctly, the right users will already look at it.

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to summon a user by notifying him in a comment? That's effectively impossible as you cannot notify someone other than the users who have commented on your question. Thus the comment would be useless.

Comment: @l4mpi: I've had people seek me out on *other* posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wow, that's definitely crossing the line. Do you flag those comments?

Comment: @l4mpi: I generally tell them of (in a polite way), ask them not to. I haven't had anyone repeat  the behaviour, so I haven't flagged anything yet.

Comment: So annoying. I've had a user summon me, right after they just posted the question, like I'm some kind of help desk. Not saying that's your situation. Just giving you my two cents from a perspective of someone who has been _"summoned"_

Comment: Someone should tell Jaydles that even when someone phrases their unpopular opinion as "I don't think this is right but..." their question will receive downvotes anyway. It looks like downvotes aren't being used to represent "disagreement" with the OP moreso "Don't do it", whatever "it" is.

Answer (score 3):

> certain users have better understanding than others

There are certain users who are willing to interpret and mentally debug a badly formulated question, and there are a few who are surprisingly good at this.

Everyone else with any knowledge on the subject could answer your question if it was actually a good question that showed what you are doing, what you have tried and what exactly you're asking. A question *rarely* is that hard that you need a specific user to answer it, it's usually just that they've seen that question in many forms that they recognize what you're actually asking.

So no, don't "summon" a professional on Stack Exchange, do some rubber duck debugging and write up a proper question.